# Add-SBHost : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am attempting to add a Host to a newly created Windows Service Bus 1.1 farm but regardless of what I do I eternally get the following error:

```
VERBOSE: [11/16/2018 2:54:06 PM]: Validating input and configuration parameters.
VERBOSE: [11/16/2018 2:54:06 PM]: Installing auto-generated certificate.
VERBOSE: [11/16/2018 2:54:16 PM]: Granting 'Log on as Service' privilege to the run as account.
VERBOSE: [11/16/2018 2:54:16 PM]: Windows Fabric configuration started.
VERBOSE: [11/16/2018 2:54:28 PM]: Windows Fabric cluster manifest generated.
VERBOSE: [11/16/2018 2:54:28 PM]: Running Windows Fabric deployment.
Add-SBHost : The system cannot find the file specified
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-SBHost -SBFarmDBConnectionString "Data Source=MYHOST;Initial C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-SBHost], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.AddSBHost
```

I had been struggling with configuring the initial deployment of the farm because my organization uses Azure AD. I was following [this very helpful Blog post](https://curtisbadke.ca/blog/2015/10/18/fun-with-installing-service-bus-for-windows/) to get through the installation and deployment but the issue I am seeing now isn't covered.

A Google of the issue leads me to [this page](http://www.wictorwilen.se/issue-when-installing-workflow-manager-1.0-refresh-using-powershell) where they talk about inspecting a DLL. I tried inspecting the `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Commands.dll` from within the Service Bus installation folder but, I'll be honest, I didn't understand enough to know what I was looking for.

Has anyone else run into this issue before? All suggestions of where I can look to find this are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research of what is actually happening in **Add-SBHost** command, this error may occur when:

1. Code is trying create new temp file in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp` directory for something called "ClusterManifest".
2. Code is trying to execute `FabricDeployer.exe` (with created "ClusterManifest" file path as parameter) in directory which is defined in registry path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Bus\1.1` for variable `WinFabric` in folder `bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0`. In my case, executable was placed in `C:\Program Files\Windows Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code.1.0\FabricDeployer.exe`
3. Code is trying to remove temp file (created in 1 point) from `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp`

After that steps and getting message `VERBOSE: [09.08.2019 13:32:26]: Windows Fabric starting.` no more file operations should be performed.

**What to do?**

1. First of all check if temp file is created in `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp` directory (sort files by modification date in explorer, run script and wait) - probably file cannot be created because of lack of permissions.
2. If file is creating properly and has XML inside, then check if Service Fabric is installed and `FabricDeployer.exe` is present in directory. In my case it wasn't there so i had to remove Windows Fabric and Service Bus. After next installation i made sure that all files were in place.

After these steps script run was successful.

I hope it will help you :)